# I need assistance on a multicolumn lookup within a range to return the row header in Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, lookup

So I've tried numerous workarounds and different formulas and approaches, but it seems I must admit defeat and ask for help. I've looked through other posts but have not found one that answers my question.

In table 1 I have two Columns, A & B. Colum A holds static data and Column B has dropdown menus with a list of data. Each row is paired.

[image: Table 1]

In table 2 I have a matrix, with Column A being identical in data to table 1, and several columns from B onwards in table 2 reflecting the same dropdown data from Column B in table 1. Table 2 has a header in Row 1, and each column from B onwards has a header, from Level 1 to Level 9.

[image: Table 2]

I am trying to produce a formula in Excel/Google Sheets that will reference the paired data per row in table 1 and return which column the data in the matrix of table 2 is, but returning the Level value in row 1 of table 2. So essentially, return the value in row 1 on table 2, being the header, in this case, the level associated with the dropdown.

I have tried different formulas below but I clearly am not getting some of the finer nuances of how it is indexing/matching and returning what I need:

```
=INDEX(Sales!$A$4:$J$4,1,SUMPRODUCT(($EM11&EN11=Sales!$A$4:$A$12&Sales!$A$4:$J$12)*COLUMN(Sales!$A$4:$J$4)))
```

```
=INDEX(Consultancy!$A$13:$J$29,MATCH(EN8&$EM8,(Consultancy!$A$13:$A$29=$EM8)*(SUMPRODUCT(--(Consultancy!$B$13:$J$29=EN8),COLUMN(Consultancy!$A$13:$J$29))-COLUMN(Consultancy!$A$13:$A$29)+1),0))
```

There are multiple categories so each associated "table 2" lives in its own tab.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: PS. I am not looking for someone to just give me the answer, I'd love to understand how to think this kind of problem through so I can solve it for myself in the future. I've web searched and ChatGPT'd but have not managed to find a way to solve this yet that I understood.

Comment: Have you tried to use FILTER (or INDEX/MATCH) to get the data that matches table 1 column A data. Wrap that in MATCH to match table 1 column B value?

Comment: PS your explanation refers to tables, while your formulas refer to cell ranges. Either use actual tables and use table reference in your formula, or don't explain it with naming it table, but describe the sheets/ranges

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll check out the FILTER function as I've never come across it before. Apologies for the confusion, they are separate tabs and the data is tabulated in a matrix-style grid but not formatted as a table. The intended use is as follows: From "Table 1" I select a row with a category in Column A, i.e. "Leadership", and for the cell next to it in Column B I select a value from the dropdown i.e. "has no experience". In another tab ("Table 2") I have the same values for "Leadership" in Column A and the dropdown values in a row from Column B to J. I need to return the header

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly this is what you mean:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$G$1,,XMATCH($B4,FILTER(Sheet2!$B$2:$G$26,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$26=Sheet1!$A4)))
```

> Where
> `Sheet2!A2:A26` holds the different consultancy types,
> `Sheet2!B2:G26` holds the different level choices,
> `Sheet2!B1:G1` holds the different levels (to be indexed),
> `Sheet1!A4` holds the consultancy type,
> `Sheet1!B4` holds the level choice (to be matched).

The filters the different choices and matches the dropdown choice to the filtered row. This returns the column number it is found starting from the filter array. Match at first value returns 1, second returns 2, etc.

If we use the result in the indexed different levels, we get the corresponding level in return.

PS  In this case you could also avoid INDEX by using:

`="Level "&XMATCH($B4,FILTER(Sheet2!$B$2:$G$26,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$26=Sheet1!$A4))`